# Trying to animate the a div as the user clicks on it.

Tags: javascript, css

I am a beginner programmer trying to create my first project that combines html, css and javascript. I have researched the topic for hours now and I would like to find an effective solution and explanation. I have an html and a corresponding java and css file. I am trying to create a memory game. I am trying to flip the cards when the user clicks it. I have read various solutions but none that I could apply straight. I am looking for a pure javascript/css solution. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> <!--making a link to the css stylesheet-->
    <script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Matching Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "title"><h1>Matching Game</h1></div>
    <div class = "infobar">
        <span>
            __stars__
        </span>
        <span>
            __move__
        </span>
        <span>
            __timer__
        </span>
        <span>
            __restart__
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class = "gameboard">
        <div class = "cardrows">
            <div class = "flip1">
                <div id = "card1" class = "card, off" onclick="flip(this.id)">
                    <div class = "cardback">
                        2
                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront ">
                        1
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip2">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip3">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip4">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "cardrows">
            <div class = "flip1">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip2">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip3">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip4">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "cardrows">
            <div class = "flip1">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip2">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip3">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip4">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "cardrows">
            <div class = "flip1">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip2">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip3">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip4">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /*few lines of code for compatibility and for correct box resizing*/
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: rgb(228, 227, 225);
}

.title {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

.gameboard {
    width: 530px;
    height: 530px;
    background-color: #92bbce;
    box-shadow: 0 0 11px 5px #00BCD4;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.cardrows {
    width: 524px;
    height: 125px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
}

.infobar {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


.cardback, .cardfront, .flip1, .flip2, .flip3, .flip4 {
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
}

.cardback, .cardfront {
/* hide back during swap */
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    transition: transform 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cardfront {
/* front placed above back element */
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);

    background-color: #108DC0;
}

.cardback {
/* back hidden at start */
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card {
    position: relative;
}

.flip1, .flip2, .flip3, .flip4 {
/*container keeps perspective */
    perspective: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
}

.flip1 {
    left: 3px;
}

.flip2 {
    left: 134px;
}

.flip3 {
    left: 265px;
}

.flip4 {
    left: 396px;
}

.on {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );

    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}

.off {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 0deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 0deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 0deg );

    transform: rotateY( 0deg );

}
```

java:

```
function flip(el) {
    console.log("flip called");
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    console.log(elem);
    elem.className = "on";
    console.log(elem);
}
```

Comment: JavaScript**, different from Java =)

Comment: who will call flip function?

Comment: @Hodrobond Yeah sorry...

Comment: @bjurecska Just for clarities' sake, the problem is creating the flip animation in plain JS, right? Or is it related to the logic of the flipping?

Comment: @VivekN the idea was to extract and send in the div with ID card1 to the function. I have read after that the best way would be to to send in the this.id. However I was just experimenting with that solution. The problem is that most solutions I have found was either the card flips as the user hovers over or the solution used jquery which i am not familiar just yet.

Comment: @Hodrobond combination of javascript and css by flipping the class and with that rotating the divs. I think I understand the logic of it. It just not sure how to instruct onclick to switch classes.

Comment: @bjurecska you were really close, just needed a tiny CSS change to specify how long the transition goes.

Comment: Thanks guys! I could not tell you how much time it took to try to combine the different solutions on the internet and it still wouldnt work. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to get the card to flip, you were pretty close!

I've just added these two css styles

```
transition: 1.0s;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

to the `.on` and `.off` classes (they need to know how long the animation runs!)

```js
function flip(el) {
  console.log("flip called");
  var elem = document.getElementById(el);
  console.log(elem);
  elem.className = "on";
  console.log(elem);
}
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /*few lines of code for compatibility and for correct box resizing*/
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgb(228, 227, 225);
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

.gameboard {
  width: 530px;
  height: 530px;
  background-color: #92bbce;
  box-shadow: 0 0 11px 5px #00BCD4;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.cardrows {
  width: 524px;
  height: 125px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
}

.infobar {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.cardback,
.cardfront,
.flip1,
.flip2,
.flip3,
.flip4 {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
}

.cardback,
.cardfront {
  /* hide back during swap */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cardfront {
  /* front placed above back element */
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  background-color: #108DC0;
}

.cardback {
  /* back hidden at start */
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card {
  position: relative;
}

.flip1,
.flip2,
.flip3,
.flip4 {
  /*container keeps perspective */
  perspective: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
}

.flip1 {
  left: 3px;
}

.flip2 {
  left: 134px;
}

.flip3 {
  left: 265px;
}

.flip4 {
  left: 396px;
}

.on {
  transition: 1.0s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.off {
  transition: 1.0s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 0deg);
  transform: rotateY( 0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h1>Matching Game</h1>
</div>
<div class="infobar">
  <span>
            __stars__
        </span>
  <span>
            __move__
        </span>
  <span>
            __timer__
        </span>
  <span>
            __restart__
        </span>
</div>
<div class="gameboard">
  <div class="cardrows">
    <div class="flip1">
      <div id="card1" class="card, off" onclick="flip(this.id)">
        <div class="cardback">
          2
        </div>
        <div class="cardfront ">
          1
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip2">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="cardback">

        </div>
        <div class="cardfront">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="cardback">

        </div>
        <div class="cardfront">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="cardback">

        </div>
        <div class="cardfront">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cardrows">
    <div class="flip1">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="cardback">

        </div>
        <div class="cardfront">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip2">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="cardback">

        </div>
        <div class="cardfront">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="cardback">

        </div>
        <div class="cardfront">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="cardback">

        </div>
        <div class="cardfront">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cardrows">
    <div class="flip1">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="cardback">

        </div>
        <div class="cardfront">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip2">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="cardback">

        </div>
        <div class="cardfront">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="cardback">

        </div>
        <div class="cardfront">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="cardback">

        </div>
        <div class="cardfront">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cardrows">
    <div class="flip1">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="cardback">

        </div>
        <div class="cardfront">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip2">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="cardback">

        </div>
        <div class="cardfront">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="cardback">

        </div>
        <div class="cardfront">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="cardback">

        </div>
        <div class="cardfront">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqwGPq

```js
function flip(el) {
  console.log("flip called");
  var elem = document.getElementById(el);
  console.log(elem);
  elem.className = "on";
  console.log(elem);
}
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /*few lines of code for compatibility and for correct box resizing*/
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgb(228, 227, 225);
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

.gameboard {
  width: 530px;
  height: 530px;
  background-color: #92bbce;
  box-shadow: 0 0 11px 5px #00BCD4;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.cardrows {
  width: 524px;
  height: 125px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
}

.infobar {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


.cardback,
.cardfront,
.flip1,
.flip2,
.flip3,
.flip4 {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
}

.cardback,
.cardfront {
  /* hide back during swap */
  backface-visibility: hidden;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cardfront {
  /* front placed above back element */
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);

  background-color: #108DC0;
}

.cardback {
  /* back hidden at start */
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  
}

.flip1,
.flip2,
.flip3,
.flip4 {
  /*container keeps perspective */
  perspective: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
}

.flip1 {
  left: 3px;
}

.flip2 {
  left: 134px;
}

.flip3 {
  left: 265px;
}

.flip4 {
  left: 396px;
}

.on {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transition: 0.25s ease;
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.off {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 0deg);
   transition: 0.25s ease;
  transform: rotateY( 0deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> <!--making a link to the css stylesheet-->
    <script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Matching Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "title"><h1>Matching Game</h1></div>
    <div class = "infobar">
        <span>
            __stars__
        </span>
        <span>
            __move__
        </span>
        <span>
            __timer__
        </span>
        <span>
            __restart__
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class = "gameboard">
        <div class = "cardrows">
            <div class = "flip1">
                <div id = "card1" class = "card, off" onclick="flip(this.id)">
                    <div class = "cardback">
                        2
                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront ">
                        1
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip2">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip3">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip4">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "cardrows">
            <div class = "flip1">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip2">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip3">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip4">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "cardrows">
            <div class = "flip1">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip2">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip3">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip4">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "cardrows">
            <div class = "flip1">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip2">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip3">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flip4">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "cardback">

                    </div>
                    <div class = "cardfront">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The only thing I changed was adding two lines of CSS to the `.on` and `.off` classes:

`transition: 0.25s ease;`

(You can learn more about using transitions  here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp and here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition?v=example )

You can change 0.25 to something else, like 1, or 0.5 ect.

Have fun!

-Sean